# how to start a process at specific port in TAO Corba?

Tags: linux, unix, port, corba, tao

Anyone please help me , i want to start a process at a specific port in TAO Corba like NameService , do i need to change anything in config file or something else ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `TAO/docs/ORBEndpoint.html` within the TAO distribution for an overview of all options.

Comment: Yes, the ORB options work for any CORBA application, just make sure you pass them into the ORB init call

Comment: Read the documentation, that explains how you should do this